# magento programatically update sort_order on option dropdown labels

Tags: php, magento

There is info on the web about how to update attribute option labels 
(e.g. http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/05/addupdate-attribute-option-values.html) but how do I only update the sort order?

The reason I wanted to do this was that I wanted to sort manufacturer by product view count. So the manufacturers with the most global views are sorted to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Its really laborious. You have to create an array of labels for each store so that you don't overwrite anything when you update. You then can attach the sort orders to that array. Here is the code to make that work:

```
//build array of labels
        $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
        $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');

        //get default label values for option
        $optionCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setAttributeFilter($attribute_code)
                ->setPositionOrder('desc', true)
                //->setStoreFilter($_eachStoreId)
                ->load();

        //build the data required to reset the labels to what they were (what a pain)       
        foreach ($optionCollection as $option) 
            $data['value'][$option->getData('option_id')][0] = $option->getData('value');


        //go through the stores one by one
        foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $_eachStoreId => $val) 
        {

            //get the labels for this attribute for that store
            $optionCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute_code)
                    ->setPositionOrder('desc', true)
                    ->setStoreFilter($_eachStoreId)
                    ->load();

            //build the data required to reset the labels to what they were (what a pain)       
            foreach ($optionCollection as $option) 
                if( $data['value'][$option->getData('option_id')][0] != $option->getData('value') )
                    $data['value'][$option->getData('option_id')][$_eachStoreId] = $option->getData('value');
                else
                    $data['value'][$option->getData('option_id')][$_eachStoreId] = '';

        }

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die; 

        //just load all products with view counts and build manufacturerValueId => totalViews array
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addViewsCount()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')
                    ;

        foreach($products as $product){
            if ($product->getManufacturer()!='') $data['order'][$product->getManufacturer()] += $product->getViews();
        }

        //now we've gotta invert this array
        //put largest value at top
        arsort($data['order']);
        foreach($data['order'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if(!isset($highest)) $highest = $value; 
            $newData['order'][$key] = $highest - $value;
        }
        $data['order'] = $newData['order']; unset($newData);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;

        $data = array('option' => $data );

        //Get the eav attribute model
        $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

        //Load the particular attribute by id
        $attr_model->load($attribute_code);

        //Add data to our attribute model
        $attr_model->addData($data);

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($attr_model->getData()); die; 

        //Save the updated model
        try {
            $attr_model->save();
            /**
             * Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation
             */
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
            Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
            $session->setAttributeData(false);
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($e->getMessage());
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

so i realize this is a super necro but if you have the attribute option_id available the easiest thing to do here is

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeCxn = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "update 'eav_attribute_option' SET sort_order='".$sort_order."' WHERE 'option_id'='".$option_id."';";
$writeCxn->query($query);
```

Throw that in a foreach loop over your resorted array and no mucking with trying to rewrite labels and what not. The gap here is if you are trying to apply sort orders on a store scope. This will not work for that but, if you just need one sort order for the options list. This is the way to go.